# Sql Join two tables ordered by both dates

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have 2 tables

Main table

```
Id_post
Id_user_post
Post
Date_post
```

Secondary table

```
Id_mentioned
Id_user
Id_user_post
Id_post
Date_mentioned
```

I have for example 13 records first table and 3 records second one.

First table records (13)

```
1 herman this is text 1 10:00:00 15/09/2016
2 jhon this is text 2 11:00:00 15/09/2016
3 carl this is text 3 12:00:00 15/09/2016
4 herman this is text 4 13:00:00 15/09/2016
5 herman this is text 5 14:00:00 15/09/2016
6 herman this is text 6 15:00:00 15/09/2016
7 jhon this is text 7 16:00:00 15/09/2016
8 herman this is text 8 17:00:00 15/09/2016
9 herman this is text 9 18:00:00 15/09/2016
10 carl this is text 10 19:00:00 15/09/2016
11 herman this is text 11 20:00:00 15/09/2016
12 carl this is text 12 21:00:00 15/09/2016
13 herman this is text 13 22:00:00 15/09/2016
```

Second table records

```
1 herman jhon 7 11:20:00 15/09/2016
2 jhon carl 10 12:30:00 15/09/2016
3 herman carl 3 14:50:00 15/09/2016
```

If i select post of hermann i want the next results, ordered by date (date published and date mentioned)

```
1 herman this is text 1 10:00:00 15/09/2016
7 jhon   this is text 7 11:20:00 15/09/20167 (date mentioned)
4 herman this is text 4 13:00:00 15/09/2016
5 herman this is text 5 14:00:00 15/09/2016
3 carl   this is text 3 14:50:00 15/09/2016 (date mentioned)
6 herman this is text 6 15:00:00 15/09/2016
8 herman this is text 8 17:00:00 15/09/2016
9 herman this is text 9 18:00:00 15/09/2016
11 herman this is text 11 20:00:00 15/09/2016
13 herman this is text 13 22:00:00 15/09/2016
```

In those results appears the post submitted by hermman and the mentioned in the second table, ordered by date_mentioned (its somenthing like twitter where in the profile, in the main results appears the own posts and the retwitts that doesnt belong to the same owner)

I tried sql join left

```
Select * from $table_posts left join $table_mentions on $table_posts.id_user=$table_mentions.id_user order by date_post,date_mentioned
```

I' ve tried too, but nothing...

```
SELECT * FROM $table_posts WHERE id_user_post=(SELECT id_user_post FROM $table_mentions WHERE id_user_post='$id_user') AND id_user_post='$id_user'  ORDER BY date_post,date_mentioned DESC
```

Comment: You're using a datetime data type, right? See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()

Comment: How is the 2nd table related to the 1st one?

Comment: by the id_post. the same id appears in both tables.

Comment: That's a function, not a data type

Comment: @Strawberry anything you can help?

Comment: I thought I already had :-(

Comment: lol, by trying a code you will.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if I understand your design correctly, you need to normalise your database. As I see, `Id_post` refers to the id in the 1st table. However you also have `User_post` refering to the user of `Id_post` which is not necessary. Now what you're describing is not a join exactly, but rather a union of the first table and the join of the 1st and second table. Something akin to:

```
SELECT t.Id_Post, t.Id_User, t.Post, t.Date_post FROM (
    SELECT a.Id_Post, a.Id_User, a.Post, a.Date_post FROM table_posts a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT b.Id_Post, b.Id_User, b.Post, c.Date_mentioned as Date_post 
    FROM table_posts b JOIN table_mentions c ON b.Id_post = c.Id_Post
) t ORDER BY t.Date_post DESC;
```

Comment: I am trying this code, but there is a mistake, it doesnt show the results expected.

Comment: What sort of results does it show vs what did you expect?

Comment: There was a minor thing with table aliases in the 2nd query. Try it again and let me know.

Comment: I finally did. thanks for your advice. I think I need to improve the sql statement, though. The problem is both tables has not the same number of rows, so I had to fill the gaps of the 2nd table with several subqueries of the first table, till matching the number of rows in both tables. I used `UNION ALL` only. I couldnt find the way to use `JOIN`.

Comment: `SELECT id_post,id_user_post,post,date_post FROM  table_posts WHERE id_user_post =  '$variable' UNION ALL 
SELECT id_post,id_user_post,(SELECT post FROM table_posts WHERE table_posts.id_post=table_mentions.id_post),date_mentioned AS date_post FROM  table_mentions WHERE table_mentions.id_user_post =  '$variable' ORDER BY date_post DESC`  this is the SQL statement I used and worked. but I want to know how do I get the same results without using the subquery. `$variable` is just the id of Herman user. If you could check it would be great.

Comment: The real statement is bigger than this one because the real 1st table has about 16 rows vs the 2nd one has about six. I had to fill those gaps with subqueries from the first table, and the statement became slow. I know is not sintactically correct, though.